# Data from View taking too long to execute (JavaDb)

Tags: sql, view, javadb

Suppose I've two tables. One is `FOLLOW_UP`, and the other is `ENQUIRY`. I've joined the tables where the last followup of a particular enquiry is displayed.

```
  CREATE VIEW F_TOFOLLOW 
          AS 
          SELECT FOLLOW_UP.ID, FOLLOW_UP.LONGDATE, FOLLOW_UP.VISITOR_ID, ENQUIRY.UNAME, 
          FOLLOW_UP.FEED_BACK, FOLLOW_UP.FEED_BACK_SUMMARY,  
          FOLLOW_UP.FOLLOWUP_BY, FOLLOW_UP.NEXT_CONTACT, ENQUIRY.CREATE_BY, ENQUIRY.IS_MEMBER  
          FROM APP.FOLLOW_UP  
          INNER JOIN APP.ENQUIRY ON FOLLOW_UP.VISITOR_ID = ENQUIRY.ID  
          WHERE FOLLOW_UP.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM FOLLOW_UP F WHERE F.VISITOR_ID = FOLLOW_UP.VISITOR_ID)
```

This query was working fine previously. But after crossing some 40,000 data it has become very slow. Is there anything wrong with the query itself ? Or How should I write an efficient query for selecting the `max id` only that depends on some other table's id. ?

Comment: Are you aware of indexes and their usage?

Comment: Yes. I know about index. I tried adding index to some of the columns. But the result is same.

Comment: Just realised you are using javadb. You might need to switch to a on disk DB like MySQL or Maria or Postgres.

Comment: @muttonUp MySQL was unable to show me the result when the data was just 10000+. But it was running fine in javadb.